# Solana Anchor deploy error. bump targets should not be provided with init. please use bump without a target

Tags: deployment, anchor, solana

When I run `anchor deploy`, I am getting this error.
`bump targets should not be provided with init. please use bump without a target`
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

What version of anchor you running ?

0.21.0 added breaking change with bumps

https://github.com/project-serum/anchor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

> lang: Providing bump =  targets with init will now error. On init only, it is required to use bump without a target and access the seed inside function handlers via ctx.bumps.get("<pda-account-name"). For subsequent seeds constraints (without init), it is recommended to store the bump on your account and use it as a bump =  target to minimize compute units used